# How Do I Change the Default Schema

Tags: sql-server-2008

On my production system I login to SQL Server with CPSDOM\mconnors. When I execute 'SELECT CURRENT_USER;' it returns 'CPSDOM\mconnors'.

On my test system I login to SQL Server with CPSDOM\mconnors. When I execute 'SELECT CURRENT_USER;' it returns 'dbo'.

Can someone help me understand what is going on? Is this difference based on a configuration setting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a login and a user on SQLServer.

Each database has a set of users and a set of logins. Logins are server-wide, users are per-database. The login can be your Windows user account or a SQLServer internal one (eg sa).

The login is mapped to a user for each database, so in the production system you have your windows user (the login) mapped to a user with the same name. In the test system they just mapped your login to the inbuilt dbo user.

You should not rely on your login being the same name as the windows account, when you setup security for the sql server, it will default-map your windows user to a new sql user of the same name, but sometimes people map it to pre-defined sql users, and sometimes for dev/test to one of the 'admin' users that already exist.

You can see this mapping in the security section of SQLServer management studio, or in the users section of the individual database.

Comment: With that in mind I went to security/logins/ Login Properties/UserMaping and entered in 'CPSDOM\mconnors' for the user. When I run 'SELECT CURRENT_USER' I still get back 'dbo'. I went back to the Login properties/UserMapping to verify the change was still there and it was. What am I missing?

Comment: @not sure - its always been a bit blackart. Do you have a user of that name in the DB? If you go to the dbo user and look at his properties, are you still listed? Have you logged off and on again?

Comment: Yes on all accounts. I'm a bit stumped, not sure where to go with this

Comment: I'd ask on DBAs stackexchange site then, or go through the SQLServer docs.